# Universalizing my program/Making it accessible to other users

Tags: python, python-3.5

So I am creating a program that takes input, processes the data, then puts it in Excel. In order to do this, I am using the "xlwt" package (and possibly xlrd). How do I then give this program to other people without making them download python and the packages associated with my program? I considered utilizing an online python interpreter and giving the username/password to my coworkers, but xlwt isn't on any of the ones I've tried, and they don't offer a way (that I can see) to download new packages.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compile the code into an exe file. The `py2exe` library can help you out with this